# How to customize the Categories meta box to allow only one category?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, metabox

I'm trying to customize the Categories meta-box when adding a post.

[image: screenshot]

I have added a custom post and I need the administrator to post a new post without the ability to use the top level categories and also, he can just choose only one category, no more than one category!

Comment: function convert_root_cats_to_radio(){global $post_type;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#activitycategorychecklist>li>label input").each(function(){
        this.disabled = "disabled";
    });
    jQuery("#activitycategorychecklist>li>ul>li>label input").each(function(){
     this.type = 'radio';
    });
    jQuery("#activitycategory-tabs li:odd").hide();
    </script>
    <?php}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'convert_root_cats_to_radio' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'convert_root_cats_to_radio' );

Comment: I have solved as the code above ,thanx!

Comment: Please add this as answer then. You can mark it as solved in two days. Help us helping you and later users with keeping the site clean.

Comment: How to mark it as solved?

Comment: Add it as answer, check back two days later, tick the check mark below the voting arrows. Thanks.

Comment: @liying, please read: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 5):

Freed from comment; the asker really did not want to write an answer. :/

```
function convert_root_cats_to_radio()
{
    global $post_type; 
    ?> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery("#activitycategorychecklist>li>label input").each(function(){ 
    this.disabled = "disabled"; 
}); 
jQuery("#activitycategorychecklist>li>ul>li>label input").each(function(){ 
    this.type = 'radio'; 
}); 
jQuery("#activitycategory-tabs li:odd").hide(); 
</script> <?php
} 
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php',     'convert_root_cats_to_radio' ); 
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'convert_root_cats_to_radio' );
```

Answer (score 1):

My [Radio Buttons for Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies) plugin converts any taxonomy (including categories) to radio buttons so that only 1 term can ever be selected.  Though I guess it doesn't handle restricting/disabling the top-level terms.